# Как адаптировать SPA под мобильную версию?

Tags: html, css, mobile-development, mobile

Имеется одна страница. Её нужно адаптировать под мобильные устройства. Как грамотно прописать @media (max-width) в .css-файле, чтобы это коснулось всех h1, h2,

, margin'ов, padding'ов ?

Как учесть вертикальное и горизонтальное расположение экранов, взяв 720px за основу?

```css
.clear {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.background-crm {
    background: url("/products/crm/images/images/crm-background.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-top: 95px;
}

.background-crm .main-container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.background-crm .main-container h1 {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #3c1a75;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.background-crm .main-container .first-block {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.background-crm .main-container .first-block p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 175px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.background-crm .main-container .second-block {
    top: 90px;
    left: 560px;
    position: absolute;
}
.background-crm .main-container .third-block {
    position: absolute;
    left: -190px;
    top: 590px;
}
.background-crm .main-container .fourth-block {
    margin-top: 295px;
    float: right;
    width: 521px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.background-crm .main-container .fourth-block h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3c1a75;
    margin: 17px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.background-crm .main-container .fourth-block ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.background-crm .main-container .fourth-block ul li {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #656a74;
}

.background-crm .main-container .fourth-block ul li:before {
    color: #656a74;
    content: '\25CF';
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="background-crm">
                <div class="main-container">
                    <h1>Crm-promo</h1>
                        <div class="first-block">   
                            <p>
                                Cистема с возможностью интеграции с сайтом,<br/>
                                социальными медиа, инструментами<br/>
                                распознавания QR кодов и т.д., позволяющая<br/>
                                собирать показатели об эффективности<br/>
                                проводимой промоакции.<br/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="second-block">
                            <img src="images/images/crm-second-picture.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="third-block">
                            <img src="images/images/crm-picture.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fourth-block">
                            <h2>Возможности:</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Выгрузка отчетов для сбора необходимых<br/>показателей по каждой рекламной кампании.</li>
                                    <li>Интеграция с сайтом и мессенджерами.</li>
                                    <li>Подключение различных дополнительных<br/>платформ (в том числе инструментарий<br/>автоматического распознавания и проверки<br/>QR-кодов).</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Обращайтесь к дизайнерам, они вам в фотошопе нарисуют как

Comment: Самое простое сверстать страницу на bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы вам рекомендовал сделать сброс всех стилей, используя reset.css или normalize.css. Если у вас большое количество текстовой информации, тут было бы удобнее использовать em, т.к легко можно будет переопределить размер всех текстов и сохранить первоначальные пропорции. Для того. что бы сделать максимально гибкую верстку с учетов всех разрешений и ориентации устройства, вам понадобится прописать  css под каждый вариант. используя @media (orientation: landscape/portrait)(min-width, max-width)(min-height, max-height)(aspect-ratio) и другие. Более подробно можно глянуть здесь https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/